# $P$ is a point in the interior of a square $ABCD$, such that $\angle DCP = \angle CAP = 25^\circ$. What is $\angle BPA$?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> Moderator Note: this is a question from the [Federal Mathematics Competition 2013](http://www.mathe-wettbewerbe.de/bwm/bwm-wettbewerb-naechster-lauf).

So here's another quite complex problem: $P$ is a point in the interior of a square $ABCD$, such that $\angle DCP = \angle CAP = 25^\circ$. What is $\angle ***PBA***$?

Does anybody have any ideas on this problem? I tried to find as much angles as I could, but I just got stuck...

Hope for some good answers :)

Markus

Comment: P.S.: I'm the German guy, so don't wonder about my language :D

Comment: Using Geogebra I found 70 degrees. Lets try to prove geometrically.

Comment: yes, it is really important for me to give good evidence for my answer... I need it for my a levels :/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was asked while it was a question from an on-going contest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the circumcircle of $CAP$. Since $\angle CAP = \angle PCD$, it follows that $CD$ is tangential of the circumcircle. Hence, the circumcenter lies on $BC$, which is perpendicular to $CD$ at $D$. Also, the circumcenter lies on the perpendicular bisector of $AC$, which is the line $BD$. Thus, $B$ is the circumcenter of $APC$.

This shows that $BA=BP=BC$, so $BAP$ is an isosceles triangle, which gives that $\angle BPA=\angle BAP = 70^\circ$.

---

It is easy to figure out $\angle PBA$ given the above.

Comment: great answer! thank you :)

Comment: Ohhhhhooho I did a big mistake!!! We are looking for "angle PBA" !!! but the rest of the task was correct

Comment: Well, I'm sure you can figure out what $\angle PBA$ is now ... Hint: sum of angles in triangle is ??

Comment: It has to be 40° :D It was too late in Germany to think properly :D

Comment: @robjohn Is there a way for me to delete my answer, since this problem arises from a live competition? I tried deleting it manually, but it refused to let me because it was accepted.

Answer (score 6):

A pictorial proof. An image to illustrate the solution given by *Calvin Lin*.
[image]

Comment: +1 for the edit :) You comment that the answer was 70 helped me figure this out quickly.

Comment: Ohhhhhooho I did a big mistake!!! We are looking for "angle PBA" !!! but the rest of the task was correct

Comment: @user55214, $\angle PBA$ is $180-70-25-45$.

Comment: =40° :D I'm a f''

Comment: =40° :D I'm a fu**in' idiot :D